# Cheapest mystic forge recipes?

Tags: guild-wars-2

What are the cheapest mystic forge recipes? This information would be helpful for completing the Daily Mystic Forgesmith achievement regularly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest forge recipe would be 4 karma-purchased items => one random karma-purchased item.

Since the items in question are bought with karma, they can neither be sold nor disassembled, but you should be able to do this with some of the 70-karma accessories (or 280 karma total -- essentially one event at max level) from the starting zones.

Comment: Thanks Raven. I picked up 16 Raven Totems for 63 karma each (1008 total) and I'll try them out next time the Mystic Forgesmith daily is up before I compare to the options that cost money rather than karma.

Comment: For what it's worth, I just put the Raven Totems into the forge and got a Separatist Wanted Poster, Grenade Pin, Pyre Fierceshot Arrowhead, and Sealed Iron Legion Ghost Trap. Combining those gave me a Deputy Peacemaker Badge.

Comment: The other two answers are good, but I chose this one because the amount of karma required can be acquired very quickly by regular play. I also noticed that Mystic Forgesmith occurs three times per cycle and Karma Spender occurs four times per cycle, while Karma spender requires you to spend 750 karma, which is almost exactly 3/4 of the amount required for this method of completing Mystic Forgesmith. So essentially you can complete two dailies for the price of one if you have the inventory space. Thanks Raven!

Answer (score 6):

Since you're just asking about *any* cheap recipes for the sake of doing your dailies (i.e. you don't really care what you get out of it), you can throw pretty much any old trash that you'd normally sell or salvage into it. Just do your daily kills etc. and, at the end of your four other daily achievements, you should easily have enough items (you'll need 20, five groups of four) to throw into the Mystic Toilet.

Just use four pieces of armour (blue or even white will do) or four weapons of any level - experiment with it, you'll notice items that won't work being disabled as you put items in. No need to throw in items that could be useful or worth something (unless of course you *do* care what you get out of it, but that's not what you were asking). Four random blue pieces of armour, for instance, will likely get you another blue item, with a small chance of getting a green.

Simple and cheap - all it will cost is that you won't be able to sell or salvage those 20 items at the end of your dailies run.

Comment: The problem there, assuming I have the inventory space to run around with 20 items that I don't want, is that I can usually sell even the worst junk I get for at least 30c to a merchant. So throwing each of those items into the forge instead of selling them is effectively costing me that amount of money. The reason I asked the question is to find a cheaper alternative.

Comment: @Brian: That's why I said "all it will cost is that you won't be able to sell ... those 20 items". As always, it's a tradeoff - if 5 to 10 silver is seriously too expensive for you (it'll take a couple of minutes to make that much by running around Orr) then this daily achievement is not for you - choose another instead (I know I do, I find others more convenient). But the fact that it's the cheapest option for this particular daily achievement remains - I'm not willing to spend karma on this since I'd rather save that for my next legendary.

Comment: I suppose the alternative is to sell everything you get as per normal and then just buy the cheapest armour/weapons availableon the TP?

Comment: @Gwen: Sure, you can try that, but given that it's only a few silver we're talking about and that buying from the TP you're always going to be paying _above_ item value, I'm not sure that's going to save you much. In fact, I'd argue that if you spend the time it would take you to make your purchases and pick them up from the TP doing an event in the Cursed Shores instead, you'll get more bang for your buck. Obviously each person needs to figure out what works best with their own playing style and preferences (e.g. if you visit the TP lots anyway, it might be worth it for you).

Comment: Personally I just make superior seige if I feel like doing this daily, because it's so awful :P At least that way I'm being useful!

Comment: @aaamos Telling me to ignore the cost when the entire question is "which option is cheapest" doesn't really support your case. You may need to save up karma for your next legendary weapon, but what I need to save up is money.

Comment: @Brian: If your _only_ concern is coins, then fair enough. In that case, I would recommend doing [other dailies](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Daily/Table). Most people with at least one level 80 character, however, will agree that the term "cheap" is always relative, and what it comes down to, essentially, is _time_. I have a limited number of hours each week to play, I know how to make money quickly, so to me, 10 silver (say) _is cheap_. Spending 10 minutes without really accomplishing anything in the game is, to me, expensive. I hope that makes sense without making me sound elitist. ;-)

Comment: @aaamos That makes sense. Simply doing other dailies doesn't solve my problem though, because I usually try to do as many of the daily achievements as I have time for. I usually don't farm (I find it too boring) so I try to keep my costs low.

Answer (score 4):

The fastest & cheapest way is to buy one each of the four cheapest dyes on the Trading Post. They typically go for 20-30 copper. No need to dig around in your bank or find karma vendors.

Comment: I liked this the most, because you can do it in 20 seconds and it is also very cheap

Answer (score 3):

Credit to one of my friends for thinking of this:

You need to already have 1 [Experience Booster](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Experience_Booster), 1 [Magic Find Booster](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Magic_Find_Booster), and 1 [Karma Booster](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Karma_Booster) for this. You buy 5 [Leather Bags](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Leather_Bag) for 32c each, then forge and open a [Booster Multipack](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Booster_Multipack) five times. This results in a total cost of only **1s 60c** for the Mystic Forgesmith daily.

Comment: That's kinda crazy of Anet - a multipack that costs the same in gems as buying the separate boosts :P